# Compare successive rows

Tags: c#, dataset

I have a dataset which I fetched from DB and now I want to verify if every successive subEvent of every Event occurs within **24 hours(1 Day)**.

Table:

```
EventId     Event    SubEvent       EventDate

 1          A      SubEvent_A1   01-10-2013 11:00 hrs  
 2          A      SubEvent_A2   02-10-2013 10:00 hrs  
 3          B      SubEvent_B1   02-11-2013 13:00 hrs  
 4          B      SubEvent_B2   03-11-2013 05:00 hrs  
 5          B      SubEvent_B3   04-11-2013 07:00 hrs   
 6          C      SubEvent_C1   05-11-2013 21:00 hrs  
 7          C      SubEvent_C2   06-11-2013 23:00 hrs
 8          A      SubEvent_A3   04-10-2013 23:00 hrs
```

After performing this check, my **Result Summary** should show as:

**SubEvent_A3 of Event A does not occur within 1 day of SubEvent_A2**
**SubEvent_B3 of Event B does not occur within 1 day of SubEvent_B2**
**SubEvent_C2 of Event C does not occur within 1 day of SubEvent_C1**

Can anyone help?

Comment: You can compare with `if`s.

Comment: I am trying to use  a new data structure ( prefereably ..Dictionary) to store the last occured subevent for each event. But it might not be a very efficient way of doing this. Any other ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you stated DataSet this solution is based on the assumption that you have a DataSet object and the table is stored in the variable `dt`.  This solution makes use of the .Net4 function zip

```
var q = (
            from r in dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
            orderby r["DateTime"]
            group r by r["Event"] into g
            select g.Zip(g.Skip(1), (DataRow x,DataRow y) => new {                              Event = y["Event"],
                SubEvent1=x["SubEvent"],
                SubEvent2=y["SubEvent"],
                Diff = (DateTime)y["DateTime"] - (DateTime)x["DateTime"]
        })
         ).SelectMany (x => x)
          .Where(x => x.Diff > TimeSpan.FromDays(1))
          .Select(x => string.Format("{0} of Event {1} does not occur within 1 day of {2}",
                                     x.SubEvent2,
                                     x.Event,
                                     x.SubEvent1));
```

`q` will now contain your list of error messages

Implementation of Zip for .Net 3.5

```
public static class ZipLinqExtension {
  public static IEnumerable<TResult> Zip<T1,T2,TResult>(this IEnumerable<T1> source1, 
                                                             IEnumerable<T2> source2,
                                                             Func<T1,T2,TResult> function) {
     using (var e1 = source1.GetEnumerator()) {
        using (var e2 = source2.GetEnumerator()) {
           while (e1.MoveNext() && e2.MoveNext()) {
              yield return function(e1.Current, e2.Current);
           }
        }
     }
  }
```

}

Comment: Thanks Bob, but I am using .NET 3.5. Any other functions which can be used in 3.5 to achieve this?

Comment: @HardBoiled Updated answer with a 3.5 implementation of Zip

Comment: Much appreciated Bob :)